# Sugarcrm: Custom save button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, button, save, sugarcrm

I've tried all day to get the above working, but using JQuery instead. When a user clicks save, I need to present them with a dialog box which asks them to choose one of three options:

```
    $(function() { 
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({ 
        resizable: false, 
        height:140, 
        modal: true, 
        buttons: 
        { 
             Option1: function() 
             {  
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 return window.old_check_form(formname);
             }, 
             Option2: function() 
             { 
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                 return false;              
             },
             Option3: function() 
             { 
                 $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                 //Do some manipulation to the field values
                 return window.old_check_form(formname);                
             } 
        }
    }); 
});
```

But it just doesn't work due to the above being called asynchronously.

Any idea how I can do the above JQuery instead of using confirm()?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Michael

Comment: I neglected to mention that this was in relation to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276643/sugarcrm-custom-save-button-using-jquery